# How can I use JavaScript to display a random field in Anki?

Tags: javascript, anki

First of all, see below for some related but not-quite-right code:

```
<div id='0' style='display:none'><p>{{Field 1}}</p></div>
<div id='1' style='display:none'><p>{{Field 2}}</p></div>
<div id='2' style='display:none'><p>{{Field 3}}</p></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById(Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)).style.display = 'inline';
</script>
```

I have an old Anki deck where I always have exactly 3 fields filled out, and therefore this code works properly to output one of them at random. The problem I'm running into now is that I'm working on a deck which will have a varying number of fields filled out per note.

Basically I'm trying to figure out how to write similar JavaScript code except where it would pick a random thing out of a varying number of things. If a field called "Field 1" is left blank in Anki, I think {{Field 1}} returns nothing. Perhaps the code could skip over any which return nothing and display a random one out of the ones that return a string (instead of picking a random field where nothing is outputted if one of the empty fields is picked)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to add a class to the elements so that we can select them all using e.g. `document.querySelectorAll('.anki-card')`?

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--- {{#field}}{{/field}} makes sure anki template engine doesn't render empty field into HTML --->
{{#Field 1}}<div class="field" style="display:none"><p>{{Field 1}}</p></div>{{/Field 1}}
{{#Field 2}}<div class="field" style="display:none"><p>{{Field 2}}</p></div>{{/Field 2}}
{{#Field 3}}<div class="field" style="display:none"><p>{{Field 3}}</p></div>{{/Field 3}}

<script>
  var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.field');
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);

  if(fields.length > 0) {
    fields[random].style.display = 'inline';
  }
</script>
```